# What are the differences between the Theatrical Release Cut and the Director's Cut of Midsommar?

Tags: alternate-version, midsommar

I've read that [*Midsommar* will have a home video release of its Director’s Cut version](https://bloody-disgusting.com/home-video/3582174/extended-directors-cut-midsommar-will-exclusively-released-apple-tv/). In the same linked article, the Director's Cut has been described to be "extended and unrated" and being the "more comprehensive version."

What are the differences between the Director's Cut and the theatrical release cut of *Midsommar*?

Comment: https://screenrant.com/midsommar-movie-directors-cut-new-scenes-meaning-explained/

Comment: @TK-421 You gotta make up your mind if you think the question is off-topic or if you want to answer it in the comments. So maybe you want to flesh out that link-only comment into a proper answer instead?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson If this question is not wrong, then I can turn my comment into an answer.

Comment: Why would this question be off-topic? There are numerous questions in this site asking about the differences between the different cuts of movies.

Comment: @TK-421 I'd love to see your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 4):

The Director's Cut of *Midsommar* which clocks in at 171 minutes includes more character development scenes that set the stage for conflicts that occur later in the film. One example occurs in the scene where Dani confronts Christian for hiding his trip to Sweden from her. In the DC, Christian gaslights Dani by accusing her of ruining the "surprise" invite he had planned for her.

There is also a longer sequence of the group of friends riding in the car after arriving in Sweden. Dani receives a birthday text from a friend foreshadowing Christian forgetting her birthday. During a conversation Pelle informs Dani that Christian "was already brainwashed when I found him."

The tense scene where Josh confronts Christian about stealing his thesis is also extended, illustrating how Christian is selfish in both his romantic relationships and his friendships. This is followed by a scene of Christian having a conversation with Maja about rituals, during which she tells him "we grieve and celebrate."

The biggest scene that was cut consists of a 15 minute stretch of theatrics that occur the night after the cliff ceremony, in the form of a community play put on by the Hårga. In it, a young boy dressed as a tree volunteers for a ritual, during which he is almost killed by two of his fellow community members. Moments before his death, they release him for proving his bravery. This is followed by another deleted scene of a fight between Dani and Christian where she begs him to leave Sweden and he refuses. He also continues to gaslight her, accusing her of "being too nice" and trying to make him look bad.